# Simple Login using ajax in php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to login using AJAX in PHP but its not working. Here is my code, please correct where required.

This is the from to enter credentials.

```
<?php session_start();?>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //alert(23424)
        $("button").click(function(){
            alert('hey');
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var pass = $("#pass").val();
            if(email===""|| pass===""){
                alert("All fields are mandatory!!!");
                return false;   
            }
            alert(email);
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "loginDB.php",
                //data: data
                data: { email: email, pass: pass}
            });
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <center><h1>ADMIN LOGIN</h1></center><hr><br>
        <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id= "email" required><br><br>
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required><br><br><br>
        <button type="button" id="button">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my verification code.

```
<?php
session_start();
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "123456";
    $dbname = "ajax";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM register WHERE email='".$email."' and password='".$pass."'";
    //echo $sql; exit;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $_SESSION["name"]= $row["name"];
           // echo $_SESSION["name"]; exit;
            header("Location:welcome.php");
            }
    }
    else {
        include 'admin_ajax.php';
        ?>
        <br><br>
        <?php
        echo "Incorrect email or and password";
    }
exit();
?>
```

Not getting what the problem is. Please help.

Comment: See the browser console

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this. You are storing passwords as plaintext, you also need to fix this.

Comment: do you getting any error in browser console.

Comment: Does the PHP code get launched? Check Apache log

Comment: try adding ajax library `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js`  you are loading only `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js`.

Comment: check your ajax response to add  "success: function (data) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript needs to be

```
$.ajax({
 method: "POST",
 url: "loginDB.php",
 dataType: "json",
 data: { email: email, pass: pass},
success:function(data)
{
if(data.type=='success')
    window.location = 'welcome.php';
else
   alert("Incorrect email or and password");
}
});
```

And in php

```
<?php
session_start();
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "123456";
    $dbname = "ajax";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM register WHERE email='".$email."' and password='".$pass."'";
    //echo $sql; exit;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            $_SESSION = $row;
            echo json_encode(array("type" => 'success'));
            exit;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        include 'admin_ajax.php';        
        echo json_encode(array("type"=>'error'));
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works :) But still it doesn't show the error message when wrong details are entered. Anyways, it helped :)